# Is there a nonlinear smooth function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(X) + X \sim N(0,1)$ when $X\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, analysis, integral-equations

Suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$. Is there a nonlinear smooth function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(X) + X \sim N(0,1)$?

Here is my attempt.
I consider the moment generating function of $X+f(X)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E} e^{t(X+f(X))} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{t x + tf(x)} e^{-x^2/2} dx = e^{t^2/2},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which can be further simplified as
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{tf(x)} e^{-(x-t)^2/2} dx = 1.
$$
This must hold for any $t\in\mathbb R$. But I don't know how to deal with this integral equation.

Is there any suggestion on this equation or an alternative approach? Thank you!

**Update**:
@Cretin2 Thanks for the suggestion.
The density of $Y=f(X) + X$ is
$$p_Y(y) = \sum_{x:f(x)+x=y} \frac{p_X(x)}{|f'(x) + 1|},$$
which is reduced to
$$ \sum_{x:f(x)+x=y} \frac{e^{f(x)(y-f(x)/2)}}{|f'(x) + 1|} = 1,$$
for any $y\in\mathbb R$. If $f(x)+x$ is not monotone, then there is some point $x_0 < x_1$ such that $f'(x_0) + 1= 0$ and $h:(x_0,x_1)\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto f(x)+x$ is injective. As $y\to h(x_0)$,
$$\frac{e^{f(h^{-1}(y)) (y - f( h^{-1}(y) )/2) }}{|f'(h^{-1}(y)) + 1|} \to \infty,$$
a contradiction. Then $f(x)+x$ must be monotone and $f$ must be linear. There is no such nonlinear transformation.

I find https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities useful (for density after non-injective transformation).

Comment: Does $f(X)=0$ count as linear?

Comment: @Henry: why not ?

Comment: @Surb because at first glance it looks like the only obvious continuous function that might work, though on further thought, $f(X)=-2X$ would work too

Comment: @Henry: Yes, I count $f(X) = 0$ as linear.

Comment: Why not simply calculate the probability density function of the variable $y=f(x)+x$, this should give a differential equation.

Comment: @Cretin2 I am not sure about your last suggestion. But a proof via density seems feasible. I didn't take this approach at first because I think $f(x) + x$ may not be injective (I didn't know the formula for a non-injective transform). Thanks!

Comment: The invariance of the pdf p gives the functional equation : $p(x)=g'(x)p(g(x))$ if one integrates should the constant of integration be considered leading to $g(x)=P^{-1}(P(x)+c)$ with P a primitive of p ?

Comment: I suppose for N(0,1) $c=0$ since the primitive is not extensible outside [0,1]. But maybe for power laws of the form $a|x|^b$ there were a nontrivial transformation letting the pdf invariant.

Comment: I think one can make only pieces of the gaussian invariant. For example with the above equation one can prove that $\frac{a}{x\log x}$ is invariant under $g(x)=x^3$.